# C++ - Defining 2 template parameters but calling with only 1

Tags: c++, templates

While working on a project I came upon this code, which I'm trying to figure out:

```
enum Attributes { ACTIVE, COMPLETE, POSITION }
template<Attributes NN,typename TT>  
TT& Set(TT&& t) 
{ 
    return typeList.get<NN>()=t; //typeList is a boost tuple
}
```

This is called later on with

```
object.Set<ACTIVE>(true);
```

There's only one template parameter in there! 
How is possible to specify a template with two parameters, and then call it with only one? I would think the Set method supposed to take 2 template parameters (Attributes and typename), like an std::map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling a function template template parameters, which are the type of the function arguments can be automatically deduced from the type of the arguments, the function is called with:

```
object.Set<ACTIVE>(true); //same as object.Set<Active,bool>(true);
object.Set<ACTIVE>(5);    //same as object.Set<Active,int>(5);
```

This is the reason one can use template functions from the standardlibrary, like `std::max` or `std::copy` without explicitely mentioning the types of the arguments.

Comment: How is it that get `argument list for class template std::pair is missing` when trying to insert a pair into a map with `pair("Rain",2)`, forcing me to call it with `pair<string,int>`? Can't the types be deduced? I'm confused.

Comment: @Lanaru pair is struct. use std::make_pair("Rain", 2);

Comment: @Lanaru: because `pair` is not a function, but the name of the type you want to construct. For types the template arguments can't be deduced. If you use `std::make_pair("Rain", 2)` on the other hand, argument deduction works fine (which is why `make_pair` is in the library)

Comment: So, am I correct in understanding that template parameters can be deduced for function templates, but not for class templates?

Answer (score 3):

The second one is deduced fom the type of argument passed to a function, in this case `bool`.

Comment: Notice that this also works with a single one: `template<typename T> T foo(T obj);` can be called as `foo(true)` and will return a `bool`.

Answer (score 1):

Read this.

> When a function template specialization is referenced, all of the
>   template arguments shall have values. The values can be explicitly
>   specified or, in some cases, be deduced from the use or obtained from
>   default template-arguments.

```
[ Example:
void f(Array<dcomplex>& cv, Array<int>& ci) {
sort(cv); // calls sort(Array<dcomplex>&)
sort(ci); // calls sort(Array<int>&)
}
and
void g(double d) {
int i = convert<int>(d); // calls convert<int,double>(double)
int c = convert<char>(d); // calls convert<char,double>(double)
}
—end example ]
```

and 14.8.2 par of this doc. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf